# How to stall jQuery Counter at where it was last left?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, counter

I have a simple jquery counter on my website. It's designed to start when it's in viewport but when you scroll further the counter resets. How can I stall the counter at where it was last left?

Pls feel free to edit or use the code:

https://jsfiddle.net/52x0uyjp/18/

```js
var isInViewport = function(elem) {
  var distance = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
  return (distance.top >= 0 && distance.left >= 0 && distance.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) && distance.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth));
}

console.log(isInViewport($('#number3').get(0)))


$.fn.jQuerySimpleCounter = function(options) {
  var settings = $.extend({
    start: 0,
    end: 100,
    easing: 'swing',
    duration: 400,
    complete: ''
  }, options);

  var thisElement = $(this);

  $({
    count: settings.start
  }).animate({
    count: settings.end
  }, {
    duration: settings.duration,
    easing: settings.easing,
    step: function() {
      var mathCount = Math.ceil(this.count);
      thisElement.text(mathCount);
    },
    complete: settings.complete
  });
}


function startCounters() {
  if (isInViewport($('#number1').get(0))) $('#number1').jQuerySimpleCounter({
    end: 52,
    duration: 5000
  });
  if (isInViewport($('#number2').get(0))) $('#number2').jQuerySimpleCounter({
    end: 52,
    duration: 5000
  });
  if (isInViewport($('#number3').get(0))) $('#number3').jQuerySimpleCounter({
    end: 52,
    duration: 5000
  });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  startCounters()
})
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
  startCounters()
})
```

```css
.projectFactsWrap {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 0px;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#projectFacts .fullWidth {
  padding: 0;
}

.projectFactsWrap .item {
  width: 33%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.projectFactsWrap .item:nth-child(1) {
  background: rgb(16, 31, 46);
}

.projectFactsWrap .item:nth-child(2) {
  background: rgb(18, 34, 51);
}

.projectFactsWrap .item:nth-child(3) {
  background: rgb(21, 38, 56);
}

.projectFactsWrap .item p.number {
  font-size: 40px;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.projectFactsWrap .item p {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.projectFactsWrap .item span {
  width: 50px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.projectFactsWrap .item i {
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}

.projectFactsWrap .item:hover i,
.projectFactsWrap .item:hover p {
  color: white;
}

.projectFactsWrap .item:hover span {
  background: red;
}

@media (max-width: 786px) {
  .projectFactsWrap .item {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
  }
}

.mTop1000 {
  padding-top: 1800px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding-bottom: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div id="projectFacts" class="sectionClass">
  <div class="fullWidth eight columns">
    <div class="projectFactsWrap2">
      <div class="item wow fadeInUpBig animated animated" data-number="52" style="visibility: visible;">
        <i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i>
        <p id="number1" class="number">52</p>
        <span></span>
        <p>Projects</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item wow fadeInUpBig animated animated" data-number="34" style="visibility: visible;">
        <i class="fa fa-smile-o"></i>
        <p id="number2" class="number">34</p>
        <span></span>
        <p>Clients</p>
      </div>
      <div class="mTop1000">
        This just gives you a space
      </div>
      <div class=" item wow fadeInUpBig animated animated" data-number="18" style="visibility: visible;">
        <i class="fa fa-coffee"></i>
        <p id="number3" class="number">18</p>
        <span></span>
        <p>Coffee</p>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You re-instantiate it every time you scroll. jQuerySimpleCounter does not have a pause

Answer (score 1):

You can use `data-attributes` to store the counter is counting like below.

All you need is to modify your counter start :

```
var isCounting = thisElement.data("isCounting");
if (isCounting) return;
thisElement.data("isCounting", true);
```

And in your animation code, add a callback that sets the data attribute to false :

```
 () => {
        thisElement.data("isCounting", false);
      })
```

**Edit:** Edited according to comments.

```js
var isInViewport = function(elem) {
  var distance = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
  return (distance.top >= 0 && distance.left >= 0 && distance.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) && distance.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth));
}

console.log(isInViewport($('#number3').get(0)))


$.fn.jQuerySimpleCounter = function(options) {
  var settings = $.extend({
    start: 0,
    end: 100,
    easing: 'swing',
    duration: 400,
    complete: ''
  }, options);

  var thisElement = $(this);
  var isCounting = thisElement.data("isCounting");
  if (isCounting) return;
  thisElement.data("isCounting", true);

  $({
    count: settings.start
  }).animate({
    count: settings.end
  }, {
    duration: settings.duration,
    easing: settings.easing,
    step: function() {
      var mathCount = Math.ceil(this.count);
      thisElement.text(mathCount);
    },
    complete: settings.complete
  }, () => {
    thisElement.data("isCounting", false);
  });
}


function startCounters() {
  if (isInViewport($('#number1').get(0))) $('#number1').jQuerySimpleCounter({
    end: 52,
    duration: 5000
  });
  if (isInViewport($('#number2').get(0))) $('#number2').jQuerySimpleCounter({
    end: 52,
    duration: 5000
  });
  if (isInViewport($('#number3').get(0))) $('#number3').jQuerySimpleCounter({
    end: 52,
    duration: 5000
  });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  startCounters()
})
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
  startCounters()
})
```

```css
.projectFactsWrap {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 0px;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#projectFacts .fullWidth {
  padding: 0;
}

.projectFactsWrap .item {
  width: 33%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.projectFactsWrap .item:nth-child(1) {
  background: rgb(16, 31, 46);
}

.projectFactsWrap .item:nth-child(2) {
  background: rgb(18, 34, 51);
}

.projectFactsWrap .item:nth-child(3) {
  background: rgb(21, 38, 56);
}

.projectFactsWrap .item p.number {
  font-size: 40px;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.projectFactsWrap .item p {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.projectFactsWrap .item span {
  width: 50px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.projectFactsWrap .item i {
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}

.projectFactsWrap .item:hover i,
.projectFactsWrap .item:hover p {
  color: white;
}

.projectFactsWrap .item:hover span {
  background: red;
}

@media (max-width: 786px) {
  .projectFactsWrap .item {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
  }
}

.mTop1000 {
  padding-top: 1800px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding-bottom: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div id="projectFacts" class="sectionClass">
  <div class="fullWidth eight columns">
    <div class="projectFactsWrap2">
      <div class="item wow fadeInUpBig animated animated" data-number="52" style="visibility: visible;">
        <i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i>
        <p id="number1" class="number">52</p>
        <span></span>
        <p>Projects</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item wow fadeInUpBig animated animated" data-number="34" style="visibility: visible;">
        <i class="fa fa-smile-o"></i>
        <p id="number2" class="number">34</p>
        <span></span>
        <p>Clients</p>
      </div>
      <div class="mTop1000">
        This just gives you a space
      </div>
      <div class=" item wow fadeInUpBig animated animated" data-number="18" style="visibility: visible;">
        <i class="fa fa-coffee"></i>
        <p id="number3" class="number">18</p>
        <span></span>
        <p>Coffee</p>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No need. The .text contains the value

Comment: Hi Eldar, thank you for your answer. Like I commented to mplungjan. 
My question was somewhat misleading. The goal is not to pause the counter (or reset it) rather then to let it count up to a specific number (start counting when in viewport) and then stall it. Hope I could clarified it. How would the code look like? Sry, I'm a bit slow today :)

Comment: Brilliant, that's exactly what I have been trying to archive. Highly appreciate it, Eldar!

Answer (score 0):

This will work better. You likely need to stop the count on exit viewport, but when you do, my code will start from where it was

```js
var isInViewport = function(elem) {
  var distance = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
  return (distance.top >= 0 && distance.left >= 0 && distance.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) && distance.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth));
}

console.log(isInViewport($('#number3').get(0)))


$.fn.jQuerySimpleCounter = function(options) {
  var settings = $.extend({
    start: 0,
    end: 100,
    easing: 'swing',
    duration: 400,
    complete: ''
  }, options);

  var thisElement = $(this);

  $({
    count: settings.start
  }).animate({
    count: settings.end
  }, {
    duration: settings.duration,
    easing: settings.easing,
    step: function() {
      var mathCount = Math.ceil(this.count);
      thisElement.text(mathCount);
    },
    complete: settings.complete
  });
}


function startCounters() {
const start1 = +$('#number1').text();
const end1 = +$('#number1').closest(".item").data("number");
const start2 = +$('#number2').text();
const end2 = +$('#number2').closest(".item").data("number");
const start3 = +$('#number3').text();
const end3 = +$('#number3').closest(".item").data("number");

  if (isInViewport($('#number1').get(0))) $('#number1').jQuerySimpleCounter({
    start: start1,
    end: end1,
    duration: 5000
  });
  if (isInViewport($('#number2').get(0))) $('#number2').jQuerySimpleCounter({
    start: start2,
    end: end2,
    duration: 5000
  });
  if (isInViewport($('#number3').get(0))) $('#number3').jQuerySimpleCounter({
    start: start3,  
    end: end3,
    duration: 5000
  });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  startCounters()
})
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
  startCounters()
})
```

```css
.projectFactsWrap {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 0px;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#projectFacts .fullWidth {
  padding: 0;
}

.projectFactsWrap .item {
  width: 33%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.projectFactsWrap .item:nth-child(1) {
  background: rgb(16, 31, 46);
}

.projectFactsWrap .item:nth-child(2) {
  background: rgb(18, 34, 51);
}

.projectFactsWrap .item:nth-child(3) {
  background: rgb(21, 38, 56);
}

.projectFactsWrap .item p.number {
  font-size: 40px;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.projectFactsWrap .item p {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.projectFactsWrap .item span {
  width: 50px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.projectFactsWrap .item i {
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}

.projectFactsWrap .item:hover i,
.projectFactsWrap .item:hover p {
  color: white;
}

.projectFactsWrap .item:hover span {
  background: red;
}

@media (max-width: 786px) {
  .projectFactsWrap .item {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
  }
}

.mTop1000 {
  padding-top: 1800px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding-bottom: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div id="projectFacts" class="sectionClass">
  <div class="fullWidth eight columns">
    <div class="projectFactsWrap2">
      <div class="item wow fadeInUpBig animated animated" data-number="52" style="visibility: visible;">
        <i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i>
        <p id="number1" class="number">0</p>
        <span></span>
        <p>Projects</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item wow fadeInUpBig animated animated" data-number="34" style="visibility: visible;">
        <i class="fa fa-smile-o"></i>
        <p id="number2" class="number">0</p>
        <span></span>
        <p>Clients</p>
      </div>
      <div class="mTop1000">
        This just gives you a space
      </div>
      <div class=" item wow fadeInUpBig animated animated" data-number="18" style="visibility: visible;">
        <i class="fa fa-coffee"></i>
        <p id="number3" class="number">0</p>
        <span></span>
        <p>Coffee</p>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, mplungjan! 
I just realized, that my question was somewhat misleading. 
The goal is not to pause the counter (or reset it) rather then to let it count up to a specific number (start counting when in viewport) and then stall it.
Hope i could clarified it.